# Creating dataframe from json not always working

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to run this code to create a data frame from a JSON link. Sometimes, the code will run. Other times, I will get an error message (below). I'm not sure why this occurs, even though the code is the same.

```
import requests
import json

url = "http://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Advanced&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2016-17&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight="

jd = requests.get(url).json()

df = []
for item in requests.get(url).json()['resultSets']:
    print("got here")
    row_df = []
    for row in item['rowSet']:
        row_df.append(str(row).strip('[]'))
    df.append("\n")
    df.append(row_df)

print(df)
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/K/PycharmProjects/mousefun/fun", line 8, in <module>
jd = requests.get(url).json()

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 812, in json return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: please don't post text as images

Comment: You need to put the traceback in your question, not in a link to an external site.

Comment: What the error message say is basically: The first character of the JSON you are trying to parse is bad already. It is either not allowed at that place or not in JSON at all.

Comment: Some of your responses are invalid JSON. Likely you're hitting some kind of anti-scrapping mechanism. Try `r = requests.get(url)`, and after that verify that `r.content` is a valid JSON before running `r.json()`.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski i tried that and i get  b' '

Answer (score 1):

Change your request logic to this and try again:

```
r = requests.get(url)
r.raise_for_status()

df = []
for item in r.json()["resultSets"]:
    # ...
```

`r.raise_for_status()` will raise if the status is not `OK` .

Also, this does not do the request two times like your code does.